# Calculate and plot mean values of pairs of data points

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, fitting, smoothing

I have a list of data points where there can be multiple y values for a given x value, e.g., {{0, 4}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}. I would like to

- Take the mean of the y values for each x value. Get a list of unique value pairs.
- Then I would like to plot the unique set of x,y values.
- Then smooth the curve
- Then fit the curve with a function.

Is there a simple way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy):

```
assoc = GroupBy[{{0,4},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3}},First->Last,Mean]
```

> <|0 -> 4, 1 -> 5/2, 2 -> 3|>

You can actually plot this association directly:

```
ListPlot[assoc]
```

[image]

But you might want to convert this to list of pairs:

```
KeyValueMap[List] @ assoc
```

> {{0, 4}, {1, 5/2}, {2, 3}}